# НЕ работает mousedown для левой кнопки мыши

Tags: jquery, cursor, mouse-event

**Стоит задание:** при зажатии мыши над объектом изменить курсор на `grabbing`.
После отпускания - изменить курсор обратно в стандартное положение.
Имею вот такой код на `jQuery`:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.swiper-container').on('mousedown', function() {
        console.log(1);
    });
});
```

И получается такая ситуация, что при зажатии на правую кнопку мыши - работает.
При зажатии на колесико - тоже работает. А вот при зажатии на левую кнопку мыши - не работает.
Тестирую сайт в браузере `Chrome 86.0.4240.111`

*То же самое поведение и для тачпада на ноутбуке.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работает ничего подобного. Просто выполняйте скрипт после загрузки документа. Так что бы в DOM появился элемент с классом swiper-container.

Chrome Версия 86.0.4240.75.

Можете протестить.

```js
$('.swiper-container').on('mousedown', function() {
  console.log(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container"> test </div>
```

Comment: Это скорее всего что апаратная проблема моего ноутбука Lenovo G70-80 или же драйверов мыши Logitech B100. Код выполняется внутри функции $(function () {}); которая и запускается после полной прогрузки DOM. Но в любом случае спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Да, все верно. Работает! Был конфликт со скриптом Swiper.js слайдера